# How To Insert New Line Using Unix CAT and Find

Tags: linux, unix, find, cat

I have the List of file that looks like this:

```
/somedir/file1.fa

>foo
ATCGGGGG

/somedir/file2.fa

>bar
CCCCCCC
```

And there are many of these files.

I want to perform a CAT using the following command

```
find /somedir/ -name "*.fa" | xargs cat > All.fa
```

But why I encounter this in `All.fa`

```
>foo
ATCGGGGG>bar
CCCCCCC
```

Instead of

```
>foo
ATCGGGGG
>bar
CCCCCCCC
```

Is there a way to correct it?

Comment: BTW I tried it n it is working fine..Can you specify the system (OS, 32/64 bit etc) you are running on? And also are you using unix version of cat/find or gnu?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your files are missing newlines at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /somedir/ -name "*.fa" | xargs -n 1 -I % bash -c "cat %; echo" > All.fa
```